# Prevent downstream Go module from using a newer version of a dependency

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a library written in Go. It depends on `github.com/example/golib v1.0.1`

A user imports my library, so they depend on my library, as well as the library my library depends on, but they run `go get -u` and it updates their go.mod to pull in the latest version of that other dependency:

```
github.com/ian/cool-library 1.0.0
github.com/example/golib v1.0.99
```

My library is incompatible with the new version of the dependency `v1.0.99`, you can only use my library with `v1.0.1`.

How do I prevent users of my library from accidentally using a newer version of that dependency?

Comment: Major versions are entirely different imports, v1 cannot be overridden by v2

Comment: If the dependency broke compatibility in a minor or patch release there’s not much you can do, other than document the requirement or update your code to match.